# Q - Chaining Sync Promises to handle success and failure

Tags: javascript, promise, q

This should be simple, I hope..

I know how to do basic promise chaining:

```
main = function() {
  returnsAPromise().then(function(data1) {
    return augmentsAndReturnsTheData(data1);
  }).then(function(data2) {
    doesSomethingMeaningfulWithTheData(data2);
  });
};
```

However, say I want to add some kind of interceptor before finally processing the data that can handle *both the success and the failure*, such as:

```
promisePrinter = function(promise) {
  var bad, good;

  good = function(data) {
    console.log(['Success', data]);
    return data;
  };
  bad = function(data) {
    console.log(['Failure', data]);
    return data;
  };
  return promise.then(good, bad);
};
```

How do I include that in my chain?  Tried a few different ways but I can't seem to get the `promisePrinter` fn to be called as I expect.

TIA!

Comment: What is it you are expecting? promisePrinter(main()); should spit out success or failure.

Comment: I was hoping to add promisePrinter to the chain opposed to passing the promise to it.  This way I can stick it anywhere in the promise flow

Comment: you can wrap each stage in promisePrinter i.e. { return promisePrinter(augmentsAndReturnsTheData(data1)); }

Comment: or extend $.Deferred so that it automatically adds the logging (either overwrite or inherit and make a custom $.LoggingDeferred which you use)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the way to do this is `promisePrinter(main())`, or `return promisePrinter(augmentsAndReturnsTheData(data1))` if you want to put it inside a given step. There's no special method for doing this on the promise prototype, like there is for `then` or `catch` or `finally`, because you're doing a very unique operation here:

- If the promises fulfills (asynchronous return), you log success, then `return` to pass through.
- If the promise rejects (asynchronous throw), you log error, then `return` to recover from that error. (If you wanted to pass the error onward, you would rethrow it.)

The existing `finally` is kind of what you want, but doesn't really fit, because it passes errors onward (like synchronous `finally`) and doesn't take a value or an error (like synchronous `finally`).